# boost ptree read_ini crashes standalone application

Tags: c++, boost, codeblocks, wxwidgets, boost-propertytree

I am using CodeBlocks and wxWidgets with minGW compiler on Windows. Under project's build options->search directories->compiler I have boost root folder, and under resource compiler wxWidgets-3.1.2/include folder.

When running application through CodeBlocks, the program runs fine with no error. But when I run .exe file of the application (from project_dir/bin), the application crashes at line read_ini (inbetween message boxes).

This is part of the code which I think is relevant:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>
boost::property_tree::ptree tree;
int result = FileDialog1->ShowModal();
if (result == wxID_OK)
{
    string f;
    try
    {
        f = string((FileDialog1->GetPath()).mb_str());
        try
        {
            wxMessageBox(_("asdf0 "));
            read_ini(f, tree);
            wxMessageBox(_("asdf1"));
        }
        catch (exception e)
        {
            wxMessageBox(_("Can't read file."));
            return;
        }
```

I have no idea how to fix this or where to start. I tried googling a bit, but no luck so far.

I will hugely appreciate any help. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: What version of boost are you using ?

Comment: @rafix07  boost_1_67_0

Comment: @rafix07 I changed, but still same crash, it doesnt catch it. 'catch (...)
            {
                wxMessageBox(_("asdf error"));
                return;
            }'

Comment: @user3007875, as I wrote on the wx forum, try to create debug build of the library and your application. This will give you an idea of what went wrong.

Comment: @Igor Yes, I am doing that now. :)

Comment: What is the reason of crash? Uncaught exception? Segmentation fault?

Comment: From what I'm seeing `mb_str()` returns `wxCharBuffer` now you convert this to `std::string` (please do not use `using namesapce std`). Is this `wxCharBuffer` contains buffer which is properly `null` terminated?

Comment: @MarekR Uncaught exception. I dont know how to check if it is null terminated but it works if I run it through IDE, so I don't know why it shouldn't work when run as a standalone application...